Resource which presents a kanji's lexemes by reading or by reading type
Is there a lexicographic resource that, for every kanji, presents a list of lexemes containing the given kanji (not necessarily in initial position) where the lexemes are ordered by the kanji's reading within that lexeme?
One possible ordering would be:

first via the category (on, kun, ateji, jukujikun, etc)
then lexicographically

The purpose of this way or organizing readings is of course to give the learner certainty about their knowledge of kanji-to-reading mappings, even if it's didactically easier to associate kanji with already-learned lexemes than to try to actively memorize kanji-to-reading rules for each kanji.
